# Searching For files

Tags: linux, centos

I am using Centos 7 and I am trying to locate the path for a folder named rhythmbox. How I can find the absolute path for a folder by searching using the name.
I tried to locate rhythmbox. and It did not work

Comment: `find | grep -i rhythmbox`

Answer (score 1):

locate command is the easiest way to find. Before searching run updatedb command. Other way is find command

```
find -name file 
find -iname file =Case Sensitive Search
```